Present perfect with "after" and "before"

I have done it many times after she came

I have done it many times before she came


I think 1 is correct because we talk about something what was done after some point in the past up to the present moment. 2 is different it isn't something done up the present moment but rather up to " before she came". That's why I think 2 is worng. Can you say if it makes sense?

(1) Since she came would be more natural. (2) I did it would be more natural.

@KateBunting  I consider 2 wrong. Do you? I know we could say "Have you ever done it before" but this before would mean the present moment.

As I said, I would recommend the simple past tense. There is no reason to use the perfect.


I have done it many times after she came.
I have done it many times before she came.

You ask if these sentences make sense. They do. An English speaker would understand what you are saying.
You also ask if they are correct. I don't think they are seriously wrong, but there are more natural ways of expressing yourself here. It also depends on context, what you actually want to say. So let me give you a real context with some examples.

I started playing golf regularly after I retired last year.
I have played golf many times since I retired last year.

This shows the difference between after and since. After suggests a point in time. Since suggests a period of time from that point until now. So the most natural tenses will be slightly different in each case.

I played golf many times before I started my new and very busy job.
I used to play golf often before I started my new and very busy job.

Here before is similar to after. It identifies a point in time. So in sentence 3 the simple past is fine. I did one thing before I did another thing. In this case the thing is over a period of time, but you don't need to use a different tense, because many times already implies an extended period. If we want to emphasise that longer period, we can do so with the phrase used to, which implies habitual action over a past period of time.

I have played golf for many years, but that was all before I started my new job.

This example shows that the perfect tense may be also valid in some settings. In sentence 5 the perfect tense suggests two periods at the same time: a life of golf over many years until now, but with most of the action pushed back into the period before I started the new job. Again, it all depends on context.
